# Why does Arrays.asList return a fixed-size List?

Tags: java, list

`Arrays.asList` is a useful and convenient method, but it returns a `List` whose size is fixed, such that no elements can be added or removed with `add` or `remove` (`UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown).

Is there a good reason for that? It looks like an odd restriction to me.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) does not explain the reason behind it:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

Comment: Create another List, e.g. `new ArrayList(asList(...))` or `new LinkedList(asList(...))`

Comment: The documentation does say it returns "a list view of the specified array" so it should make sense to have it fixed-size.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The point is that `Arrays.asList` is returning a *view* of the array, and that changes to the array are reflected in the `List` and vice versa.  It's not making a copy, it's just a very simple implementation of the `List` interface that interprets the specified array as a `List`.  As a result, `Arrays.asList` is really just reflecting that Java arrays are fixed-size, too.  You can't add or remove elements from the backing array, either.

As mentioned in the comments, it's quite easy to get a variable-size list from an array with e.g. `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array))`.

Also, for what it's worth: Guava actually [regrets](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Lists.java#L75) providing a "resizable list from varargs arguments" method after discovering that most people who used it actually really wanted an immutable list.